# Is it safe to memset the plain struct with user-defined default constructor?

Tags: c++

I know that if a C++ struct is Plain Old Data ("POD") then this guarantees there is no magic in its memory structure, so it means a `memcpy` to an array of bytes and `memcpy` back is safe.

I also know that in the standard a POD struct should not have user-defined constructor. In the project I own now, there are some plain structs (with only data fields) with a default constructor defined which initializies the data members to 0. I saw other clients would use `memset(&obj, 0, sizeof obj);` before using the struct.

Is it ok or safe to `memset` the non-POD struct before I use it?

Comment: What is POD in this context?

Comment: probably undefined behaviour but always work

Comment: C++ Plain Old Data. And in my case, the struct is nearly a POD struct (only data fields) but with the default constructor.

Comment: There are or have been actual, very successful systems on which the null pointer value is not all-bits-zero.

Comment: @jthill: TonyD raised the point that being able to use `memcpy` safely does not mean being able to use `memset` safely which I think is the key here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a constructor does not make a `struct` non-POD.

> An aggregate class is called a POD if it has no user-defined copy-assignment operator and destructor and none of its nonstatic members is a non-POD class, array of non-POD, or a reference.

Given that, it is perfectly safe to call

```
memset(&obj, 0, sizeof obj);
```

on an object of a `struct` that has a constructor as long as it is a POD.

Whether it is OK or not, depends. If the default constructor of the `struct` wants a member to be initialized to `1` for sane behavior, the above call to `memset` may impact the behavior of code that depends on `1` being the default value.

Take the example of the following `struct`:

```
struct Direction
{
   Direction() : x(1.0), y(0.0), z(0.0) {}
   double x;
   double y;
   double z;
};
```

An object of type `Direction` expects that at least of one of the components will be non-zero. You can't define a direction when all the components are zero. If you use `memset` to set everything to `0`, code will likely break.

**EDIT**
It appears, from the comments below, as though the definition of a POD has changed from C++03 to C++11.

Using `memset(&obj, 0, sizeof obj);` may not be safe after all.

Comment: But I saw the SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special#4178176 says "An aggregate is an array or a class (clause 9) with no user-declared constructors (12.1)"

And I look up the standard `n3242.pdf` page 203, it also describes the same paragraph.

It looks the Aggregates can only have default constructor generated by compiler.

Comment: @ChenOT if you follow that link a little bit down, it goes to describe POD structs.

Comment: I've read the following part of that post. What I understand is if the type is not even a aggregate, it is not a POD. And the type with a user-declared constructor cannot be a aggregate.

Comment: @ChenOT that's not how I interpreted the language.

Comment: 9.10: "A POD struct is a non-union class that is both a trivial class and..."; 9.6: "A trivial class is a class that has a default constructor (12.1), has ***no non-trivial default constructors***..."; 12.1/4: "A default constructor is trivial if it is ***not user-provided*** and...".

Comment: @TonyD, that makes sense. What do you make of the paragraph that quoted from that answer? Was that a wrong interpretation on the part of the author?

Comment: @RSahu The answer you've quoted says it's based on "C++ standard (C++03 9 §4)" - I'm quoting C++11, final draft.  Things may have changed.  More generally, the question is about knowing two things: 1) if `memcpy` is safe - that is much better asserted at compile time with [is_trivially_copiable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) than deduced once by the programmer and hoping maintenance programming won't break it, and 2) if `memset()` is safe: I doubt if it is portably even for POD - e.g. all 0 bits might not be valid for some weird `float`/`double` representation.

Comment: @TonyD: Indeed, it's important to differentiate `memcpy` and `memset`!

Answer (score 0):

IMO this depends on the use case. I have seen memset used to set the data with white space character on few mainframe appications i.e

```
memset(&obj, ' ', sizeof(obj));
```

In case the struct defines a const variable and initializes the value, memset would override such value. So it depends and most cases safe to use memset to initialize for PODS. thats my 2 cents.